# Pagination with Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails

All the examples of Kaminari I have seen only have 1 variable in the controller action.

But here is my example:

```
  def index
    @draft_item = @account.draft_item # only ever one
    @in_force_item = @account.in_force_item # only ever one
    @historical_items = @account.lo_items.historical # many of these

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

These are all displayed in a table on the view, which I want to paginate.  Do I need to combine these into 1 array first in the index action?

My loop on the view is like this:

```
 <% [@in_force_item, @draft_item, @historical_items].compact.flatten.each do |lo_item| %>
```

then I have code like:

```
<% if lo_item == @draft_item %>
```

Is this possible and still be able to call the line above>?

Thanks to the answer below, I was able to do it like this:

```
@total_items = Kaminari.paginate_array([@draft_item, @in_force_item, @historical_items].compact.flatten).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

It all had to be on one line for it to work, unlike the answer below which had it split across two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is. Kaminari has [paginate_array](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#paginating-a-generic-array-object)

```
@draft_item = @account.draft_item # only ever one
@in_force_item = @account.in_force_item # only ever one
@historical_items = @account.lo_items.historical

@total_items = [@in_force_item, @draft_item, @historical_items].compact.flatten

Kaminari.paginate_array(@total_items).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Then

```
<% @total_items.each do |lo_item| %>
<% end %>
<%= paginate @total_items %>
```